# Does Vegeta new transformation/form has an official name already?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

In the last episode of Dragon Ball Super, Vegeta got a new transformation/form. He eyes has pupils, he's super saiyan blue aura is darker and it has more sparks. Does this new transformation/form has an official name already?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Super Saiyan Blue 2 :P

Comment: i've heard ultra blue but I don't think that's canon

Comment: Not official, however, it seems to be similar to Freiza unlocking True Golden Freiza. Maybe this is the true Super Saiyan Blue transformation?

Comment: An animator said the aura has some features in common with Ultra Instinct aura. And when Vegeta was dodging Hiren hits Wiss said perhaps Vegeta was close to Ultra Instinct. May be this transformation is something close to Ultra Instinct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name is ***Super Saiyan God Super Saiyan Evolution***, official name from Dragon Ball Heroes (which is non canon but official)

[Vegeta new form official name](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kEbu0YH8Wpg)